# Netty Channel.close() hangs intermittently

Tags: netty

Netty Channel.close() occasionally hangs. In our particular use case, we have a pool of channels and our tests check for tolerance to network glitches. So, in our tests, we try to close one channel.

In the following code snippet, we print debug statements before calling Channel.close(), immediately after Channel.close(), and after ChannelFuture.await(). To make sure the thread is not being interrupted, we check for an InterruptedException.

```
        Channel c = partitionChannelMap.get(partition);
        if (c != null) {
            for (int retries = 0; retries < numRetries; retries++) {
                try {
                    logger.debug("Attempt {}: Closing channel to partition {}", retries + 1, partition);
                    logger.debug("Channel Properties - isBound() isConnected() isOpen() " + c.isBound() + " "
                            + c.isConnected() + " " + c.isOpen());
                    ChannelFuture closeFuture = c.close();
                    logger.debug("About to wait");
                    closeFuture.await(nettyTimeout);
                    if (closeFuture.isSuccess()) {
                        logger.debug("Attempt {}: CLOSED channel to partition {}", retries + 1, partition);
                        partitionChannelMap.remove(partition);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        logger.error("Attempt {}: FAILED to close partition {}", retries + 1, partition);
                        continue;
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    logger.error("Attempt {}: FAILED to close partition {}", retries + 1, partition);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In some of the runs (erroneous ones), the debug statements before Channel.close() are executed, while those immediately after do not. As Channel.close() is asynchronous, we were expecting it to return immediately. In these cases, the execution hangs after calling Channel.close().

Am I assuming or doing something wrong here?

Sample output for an erroneous execution -

```
15:12:32.497 [Thread-7] DEBUG org.apache.s4.comm.tcp.TCPEmitter - Attempt 1: Closing channel to partition 0
15:12:32.497 [Thread-7] DEBUG org.apache.s4.comm.tcp.TCPEmitter - Channel Properties - isBound() isConnected() isOpen() true true true
```

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in my code.

I call Channel.close() in a synchronized block. The close() interferes with concurrent in-flight message transfers and asynchronously invokes the operationComplete() of the failed transfers. It so happens that the operationComplete() handler also tries to close the same channel, leading to a deadlock.